# Selenium - identify web element using src or alt

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, src, alt

There is a website with an image button on it which I am trying to click using selenium. The code for this from inspecting the element is:

```
<img src="../images/aaa.gif" width="100px" height="100px" border="0" alt="aaa">
```

I know how to use find_element_by_name, id, etc...but am unsure how what to use to click the above. Could anyone advise please?

PS. The image also has a href on a seperate line of code if that makes things simpler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It the image is always exactly the same, try this xpath:

```
//img[@src="../images/aaa.gif"]
```

Comment: Or with text on the page?

Answer (score 1):

If the image always has the same `ALT` attribute you can also use the CSS selector, `img[alt='aaa']`.